# Python PIL save text in separate images

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Good day.

I am trying to create a for loop to read the lines of a file until a condition is met so it can write these lines in a image and i plan to do this with every line of the file, like the example below:

```
Number: 123456789
Connecting to Database

no rows selected

Disconnecting from Database

Number: 9876543211
Connecting to Database

1111;48446511911986;Helen;Thursday
2222;48498489489489;Helen;Friday
3333;84545221185986;Helen;Monday

Disconnecting from Database

Number: 963852741
Connecting to Database

1234;123456789456123;Clyde;Friday
4321;123456789456123;Clyde;Thuesday
1423;123456789456123;Clyde;Sunday
2341;123456789456123;Clyde;Friday

Disconnecting from Database

Number: 456987321
Connecting to Database

no rows selected

Disconnecting from Database
```

As you can see every time the word Database shows up for the second time the next line is about a new number information, so i tried using the word database as a parameter for the loop below.

```
import os
import PIL
import PIL.Image as Image
import PIL.ImageDraw as ImageDraw
import PIL.ImageFont as ImageFont


img = Image.open("C:/Users/dir/image/black_background.png")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

fonts_dir = os.path.join(os.environ['WINDIR'], 'Fonts')
font_name = 'consolab.ttf'
font = ImageFont.truetype(os.path.join(fonts_dir, font_name), 15)
x = 2
y = 0
next_print_count = 0
filename = "info.txt"
Number = ""

for line in open(filename):

    if 'Number:' in line:
        Number= line.split(" ",1)[1].strip()

    if 'Testing ' in line:
        line = ""

    draw.text((x, y),line,(200,200,200),font=font)

    y += 15
    img.save(Number + ".png")
```

Problem is that every time it starts a new file it also prints the information from the previous lines as well. How do i avoid that?

I also tried to use NUMBER as a parameter as well but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to delete the current `img` and `draw` object every time line is `"Disconnecting from Database"` and make new objects after deleting them. In your original code, you were also saving the image every line, which is not good either. See the code below.

```
import os
import PIL
import PIL.Image as Image
import PIL.ImageDraw as ImageDraw
import PIL.ImageFont as ImageFont




fonts_dir = os.path.join(os.environ['WINDIR'], 'Fonts')
font_name = 'consolab.ttf'
font = ImageFont.truetype(os.path.join(fonts_dir, font_name), 15)
x = 2
y = 0
next_print_count = 0
filename = r'info.txt'
Number = ""

with open(filename) as f: 
    img = Image.open("C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures/Chrysanthemum.jpg")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    for line in f:
        if 'Number:' in line:
            Number= line.split(" ",1)[1].strip()

        if 'Testing ' in line:
            line = ""

        draw.text((x, y),line,(200,200,200),font=font)
        y += 15

        if 'Disconnecting from Database' in line:
            img.save(Number + ".png")
            del draw, img
            img = Image.open("C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures/Chrysanthemum.jpg")
            draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
            y=0
```

results in (only showing two samples images here, but 4 are created)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Very glad to help you. If you find this answer useful and solves your problem, please consider upvoting it and accept the answer. Thanks!